# jQuery code document ready is not executed on the page, only from the browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, document, document-ready

I'm curious why the code below isn't executed when the page loaded. It's in the page.

```
<script>
    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined'){
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#mydiv .myclass:odd").css('color', 'green');
        });
    }
</script>
```

and this code is executed from the browser console after the page (the same page) loaded:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#mydiv .myclass:odd").css('color', 'green');
});
```

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code of that page and can't modify it. However I need an answer.

What could be the reason?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is unnecessary parameter. Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydiv .myclass:odd").css('color', 'green');
});
```

If you have any conflicts with other libraries, please, use jQuery in no conflict mode:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j("#mydiv .myclass:odd").css('color', 'green');
});
```

Comment: In this case it says TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' which means $ variable gets rewritten by another framework which is true.

Comment: Oh, ok. You can add `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` to the top of your script and use `$j(document).ready(function() ...` afterwards to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain then why there are no conflicts if I execute the code in the browser console in this case?

Comment: It depends on a code. You can check that is causing a conflict by adding `console.log($);` before your calls in script and check your console.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydiv .myclass:odd").css('color', 'green');
});
```

Please use the above code and add jquery.js in html file so that it will understand the $ parameter. or add var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Doesn't executing the code I described above IN THE BROWSER CONSOLE with no mistakes and with no conflicts mean jquery.js is in html file? Thank you.

Comment: please check whether jquery.js file has been added in your html file or not?

Comment: Your <script> tag code is executing before the jquery file is ready for execution thatswhy.

Comment: if you can use onload in body tag and then try to execute this code it will run because this will run only when jquery files are fully loaded.